# Align lines of text to center in SVG

Tags: css, text, svg, alignment, tspan

I need to output multiple lines of text in SVG.
For that I'm using the following scheme:

```
<text>
  <tspan> First line </tspan>
  <tspan> Second line </tspan>
</text>
```

First and second line of the text can have different number of characters, which can change dynamically.
I want the second line to appear under the first line and text in both of them to be centered.

I can make second line appear below the first line by adding `dy="15"` for the second `<tspan>`.

I can align the text in each individual `<tspan>` by adding `text-anchor="middle"` to it.

But how to do relative centric alignment of those `<tspan>`'s?

I tried to use `x="0"` for each `<tspan>` but apparently it doesn't work since each `<tspan>` has different width and the rendered text in the shorter line is shifted to the left.

Is there a way to align centres of 2 `<tspan>`'s of different width using only CSS and/or SVG.

Comment: ` text-anchor="middle"` ?

Comment: I added all the attributes you mentioned above and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/e4bAh/

Comment: Vertically center : `alignment-baseline="middle"` / Horizontally center : `text-anchor="middle"`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you add `text-anchor="middle"` to *each* `tspan` you will center them (you have to remove the space *between* the tspans as well, otherwise the extra space will be considered as part of the first line and they won't be completely centered).

For example:

```
<svg>
    <text y="50" transform="translate(100)">
       <tspan x="0" text-anchor="middle">000012340000</tspan><tspan x="0" text-anchor="middle" dy="15">1234</tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```

See: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/e4bAh/)**

Comment: +1 because this answers the multiline portion of the question using `dy` as OP suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This resolved the problem. Funny enough, the space was really responsible for the misalignment of the lines.

Comment: I think you forgot a point: `translate(100)`, where 100 is half the width of the svg, makes the base point is at center such that `x="0"` and `text-anchor="middle"` bring us the texts centered

Comment: Thanks @Eric. I was also looking for `transform="translate(100)"`, since `x` in the `tspan` overrides `x` in the `text`, and I wanted the `tspan`s placed relative to the `text`.

Answer (score 41):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5q9K8/35/)**

[image]

`text-anchor='start'` for right align.

`text-anchor='middle'` for middle align.

`text-anchor='end'` for left align.

Code from demo:

```
<svg width="100%" height="230" viewBox="0 0 120 230"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

    <!-- Materialisation of anchors -->
    <path d="M60,15 L60,110 M30,40 L90,40 M30,75 L90,75 M30,110 L90,110" stroke="grey" />


    <!-- Anchors in action -->
    <text text-anchor="start"
          x="60" y="40">This text will align right</text>

    <text text-anchor="middle"
          x="60" y="75">This text will align middle</text>

    <text text-anchor="end"
          x="60" y="110">This text will align left</text>

    <!-- Materialisation of anchors -->
    <circle cx="60" cy="40" r="3" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="75" r="3" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="110" r="3" fill="red" />

<style><![CDATA[
text{
    font: bold 15px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
]]></style>
</svg>
```

Read more about text-anchor property **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor)**

Comment: The two tspan tags actually appear on the same line (and the demo doesn't use the given code example)…

Comment: Although the demo provided isn't really a direct answer to the question, I had to upvote it because the demo shows the other options to align the text. +1 for that.

Answer (score 10):

Key points to horizontally centering the text:
 1. `x="50%"`
 2. `text-anchor='middle'`

In your case, you may write as:

```
<svg style="width:100%">
  <text y="50">
    <tspan x="50%" text-anchor="middle"> First line </tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" dy="15" text-anchor="middle"> Second line </tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Key point is: svg isn't css, you're not centering the text within a box or something, think of `x="50%"` like a cursor, x must be centered, `ŧext-anchor="middle"` just define the text origin (that will be placed at x)