# How do I align text center in HighCharts spiderWeb xAxis Categories?

Tags: highcharts

This is my chart image

[image]

I tried to make the xAxis Category text align, so I used style text align: center in some ways, but none of them went well. For example, values like BBBBBB and 100 are not aligned in the center. So is there a way to make it the center?

the chartoption code is like this

```
{
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            polar: true,
            type: 'area',
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'SUIT'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                '<span style="text-align: center"><span style="color:#404040; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;">' +
                    radarDataTitle[0] +
                    '</span><br><span style="font-size:20px;color:#002d84; font-weight:700;">' +
                    radarData[0] +
                    '</span></span>',
                '<span style="color:#404040; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;">' +
                    radarDataTitle[1] +
                    '</span><br><span style="font-size:20px;color:#002d84; font-weight:700; text-align: center; width: 100%">' +
                    radarData[1] +
                    '</span>',
                '<span style="color:#404040; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;">' +
                    radarDataTitle[2] +
                    '</span><br><span style="font-size:20px;color:#002d84; font-weight:700;">&nbsp' +
                    radarData[2] +
                    '</span>',
                '<span style="opacity:0;">2</span><br><span style="color:#404040; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;">' +
                    radarDataTitle[3] +
                    '</span><br><span style="font-size:20px;color:#002d84; font-weight:700;">' +
                    radarData[3] +
                    '</span>',
                '<span style="color:#404040; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;">' +
                    radarDataTitle[4] +
                    '</span>&nbsp<br><span style="font-size:20px;color:#002d84; font-weight:700;">' +
                    radarData[4] +
                    '</span>',
                '<span style="color:#404040; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;">' +
                    radarDataTitle[5] +
                    '</span>&nbsp<br><span style="font-size:20px;color:#002d84; font-weight:700;">' +
                    radarData[5] +
                    '</span>'
            ],

            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                distance: 30
            },
series: [
            {
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                data: radarData,
                pointPlacement: 'on',
                marker: {
                    radius: 1
                }
            }
        ],
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html-in-highcharts) and by inspecting the page source, html code is transformed to svg text elements, in particular `span` is transformed to `tspan`. A solution to align multiline text in svg with `tspan` can be found [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272040/align-lines-of-text-to-center-in-svg).

Highcharts is smart enough to use both `span` or `tspan`, but I'm more comfortable with setting the right attributes to the right element, so I'd use `tspan`:

```js
   '<tspan style="color:#404040; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;">' +
      radarDataTitle[1] +
   '</tspan><tspan x="0" dy="21" style="font-size:20px;color:#002d84; font-weight:700; text-align: center; width: 100%">' +
      radarData[1] +
   '</tspan>',
```

Note the missing `<br>` and the missing outer span that you have in the first label only.

There should be no space between the closing first `tspan` and the opening second `tspan`.

If you want to move to left or right the `tspan`s, you should use `dx` attribute (see the CCCCCC case in my example), don't change the `x` attribute since highcharts is changing 0 or missing x to the actual absolute position, but is not able to perform calculations using other values.

Here's a [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fec2uL5h/).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this?

Here's an updated code.

```
chart: {
 type: 'area',
 margin: [50, 50, 50, 50], // Adjust the margins as needed
 spacingTop: 50, // Adjust the top spacing as needed
 spacingBottom: 50, // Adjust the bottom spacing as needed
 spacingLeft: 50, // Adjust the left spacing as needed
 spacingRight: 50 // Adjust the right spacing as needed
},
```

This is alternative ways,

I don't know if this will work, but you can try adjusting the chart's positioning using the chart.margin and chart.spacing properties.

Comment: not working :-(. Thanks for the answer

Comment: i'll just update my code. it seems Highcharts doesn't support HTML markup within the categories array directly.